# How to get value conditionally from another row in sub table

Tags: sql-server

[image]

```
Select * from LoanAccount main INNER JOIN LoanSubAccount sub 
WHERE main.LoanAccountID = sub.LoanAccountID
AND sub.LoanStatus = 4
```

My objective is to retrieve rows with `LoanStatus = 4` but replace the amount with records with `LoanStatus = 2`. 
End result expected to be [image]

Comment: How do you connect rows 1 and 2 to rows 3 and 4?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: These 4 records are belongs to same `LoanAccount` and the number of rows with `LoanStatus = 2 ` will always the same as number of rows with `LoanStatus = 4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LoanAccountID, LoanStatus
                              ORDER BY LoanSubAccountID) rn
    FROM LoanSubAccount
)
SELECT t1.LoanSubAccountID,
       t1.LoanAccountID,
       t1.LoanStatus,
       t1.CommodityType,
       t2.Amount
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn AND
       t1.LoanStatus > t2.LoanStatus
```

Rather than giving a verbose explanation, I would rather show a table representing what the above CTE would look like:

```
rn | LoanSubAccountID | LoanAccountID | LoanStatus | CommodityType | Amount
1  | 1                | 1             | 2          | 1             | 100
2  | 2                | 1             | 2          | 2             | 200
1  | 3                | 1             | 4          | 3             | 150
2  | 4                | 1             | 4          | 4             | 150
```

If I read your requirement correctly, you want to connect rows having the same row number from the two different loan statuses.  The join query I gave above does this.